# Contour integral of $z^2 + \bar z$ along C: $|z-z_0| = R$

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to solve the following contour integral:

$\oint_c (z^2 + \bar z )dz$             with C: $|z-z_0|=R$

My initial thoughts were just splitting the integral in two parts, the first one being over $z^2$, which then would be 0 due to Cauchy's integral theorem. The second part with $\bar z$ made me doubt, since Cauchy's theorem only works for holomorphic functions (and $\bar z$ does not seem holomorphic to me). Could anyone help me compute this integral? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right: the integral of $z^2$ *is* zero, by Cauchy's theorem. And you are also right when you claim that you can't apply that theorem to $\overline z$. Then, use the definition:$$\oint_{\lvert z-z_0\rvert=R}\overline z\,\mathrm dz=\int_0^{2\pi}\left(\overline{z_0+Re^{it}}\right)Rie^{it}\,\mathrm dt=Ri\int_0^{2\pi}\left(\overline{z_0}+Re^{-it}\right)e^{it}\,\mathrm dt.$$

Answer (score 0):

You can make that $\overline z$ term into a function with only an isolated singularity and then use the Residue Theorem.  To wit:

$|z-z_0|=R$

$|z-z_0|^2=(z-z_0)(\overline z-\overline{z_0})=R^2$

$\color{blue}{\overline z=\overline{z_0}+\dfrac{R^2}{z-z_0}}$

Then from the Resudue Theorem, the counterclockwise contour integral of $\overline zdz$ around the circle will be $2\pi R^2i$ or **$2i$ times the area enclosed by the contour.**  That product actually applies for a clockwise integral  of  $\overline z dz$ around **any simple closed curve.**